# Show images on Django Non Rel Templates using Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

I'm doing an app with Django Non Rel on GAE, and i want to show the Profile Image of the user in the template but i can't here is the model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class userProfile(models.Model):

    def url(self, filename):
        url = "MultimediaData/Users/%s/%s"%(self.user.username, filename)
        return url

    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    email_public_user = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    url_user = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    company_user = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    position_user = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    photo_user = models.ImageField(upload_to=url)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

For now i'm adding the photo via admin to see if i can show the image, here is the template

```
<div class="navbar-header  nav-img">

     {% if user.get_profile.photo_user %}       

          <img class="navbar-brand" src="{{user.get_profile.photo_user}}">

          <p class="navbar-brand">{{user.get_username}}</p>

     {% else %}

          <img class="navbar-brand" src="/media/img/principal_html/img1.png">

          <p class="navbar-brand">{{user.get_username}}</p>

     {% endif %}
```

It shows the username, but not the image, i put the user.get_profile.photo_user in a

and i got this

```
ahRkZXZ-c29mdHN5c3RlbWFuYWdlcnIiCxIVX19CbG9iVXBsb2FkU2Vzc2lvbl9fGICAgICAzKYKDA/MultimediaData/Users/[username]/img.jpg
```

There's no view yet because im uploading the image using the django admin and when i save the user with his photo shows the same url

How can i solve this? I need to show the image...plz help

Comment: You should upload the photo to Google Cloud Storage, and store its url in the UserProfile model.  If you want to store it in the datastore, use a blob field, and you'll need a url handler to serve up the image when someone hits the `MultimediaData/Users...` url.

Comment: Yes, what @GAEfan said. If you have the final code that works, please share/answer.

Comment: Today im gonna work on that problem, ill try blob handlers